# Cosa sono "ragazze toste" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> "Questa figlia, signor Orazio, tiene una faccia poco buona. Parlo per coscienza, ché alle Zoccolette vogliono *ragazze toste* e la superiora ve la rimanda a casa. Io dico sempre: aria bona e divozione mantengono la salute".

Queste sono le parole che Tuzia dice a Orazio Gentileschi per cercar di convincerlo che sua figlia Artemisia dovrebbe andare a spasso. Così potrà prendere questa "aria bona" che le darà salute e poi essere ammessa dalle suore senza problema.

Ho cercato il significato di "tosto" in alcuni dizionari, ma non capisco cosa vuol dire "ragazze toste" nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'espressione viene spesso utilizzata con accezione negativa (si veda nel seguito); tuttavia nel passo citato il significato è un altro *([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tosto1/))*:

> Nel linguaggio fam., **riferito anche a persona, con il sign. di ostinato, testardo**, che non cede facilmente, come valutazione non necessariamente negativa, anzi spesso associata a un giudizio di energia e risolutezza:è un **tipo t.,** *che non cede e non si scoraggia alla prima difficoltà.*

La ragazza di cui si parla nel brano ha una «faccia *poco buona*» (cioè poco raccomandabile o che comunque non ispira molta fiducia), non come le ragazze che cercano alle Zoccolette, dove vogliono «tipe toste» (cioè *risolute e determinate*, cfr. [Il Correre](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_sinonimi_contrari/T/tosto.shtml)), con «aria *buona* e devozione», cioè manifestanti volontà alla sottomissione ed alla dedizione al culto religioso o ad *[altre attività](http://roma.repubblica.it/dettaglio/quelle-zoccolette-nel-palazzo-la-casa-delle-fanciulle-senza-marito/1302705)* (e qui non nascondo il sospetto che tutto il passo sia velatamente ironico ed antifrastico).

---

Il significato originario dell'aggettivo *[tosto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tosto1/)* è quello di:

> [lat. tostus, part. pass. di torrere«disseccare, tostare»]. – **Duro, sodo, non molle e cedevole**: *pane t.; carni t.*.

In senso figurato, dunque, l'espressione *faccia tosta* e, per estensione, *persona tosta/tipo tosto* vengono utilizzate anche (e soprattutto) per descrivere un individuo *[sfacciato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sfacciato_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)*, sfrontato, che resta imperturbabile di fronte alle azioni - spesso negative - che commette o alle parole - non di rado inopportune o indelicate - che proferisce *([La Repubblica](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/tosto.php))*:

> fig. **Faccia tosta**, sfrontatezza, sfacciataggine: *mi ha chiesto di favorirlo con una faccia tosta da sbalordire;* estens.**persona sfrontata**, sfacciata: *sei una bella faccia tosta*.

Comment: Questa spiegazione del Treccani l'aveva già letta e continuo senza capire molto bene. Dal contesto mi sembra che qui l'aggettivo "tosto" abbia qualcosa a che vedere con la buona salute delle ragazze o con essere forti o qualcosa di simile. Non mi sembra credibile che le suore vogliano ragazze sfrontate o testarde.

Comment: Non sfrontate o testarde (che è l'accezione negativa dell'aggettivo), ma [risolute e determinate](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_sinonimi_contrari/T/tosto.shtml), aventi *devozione* in quel che sono chiamate a fare: > (spec. nel l. giovanile) deciso, determinato, risoluto, bravo, efficace.

Comment: Se è così, potresti aggiungerlo a la risposta in modo più chiaro?

Comment: Charo, fatto. Spero di essere stata più chiara.